# simply switch to another layout with an int

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, switch-statement

I'd like to know if it's possible to create an array of layout, to be able to change the layout by switching of layout with a simple int.

Maybe there's another way, if yes can you explain it to me ?

Comment: WHYTB (What Have You Tried Before) ??!!

Comment: As long as the layouts all contain the same fields, with the same resource ids I can't see why this would be a problem.

Comment: @mansoulx I didn't really tried anything ... and the solution is very simple I feel so dumb right now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make array of layout and can set based on any int value.

// List of layout Ids

```
int layoutIds[]={R.layout.layout1,R.layout.layout2 ,R.layout.layout3,R.layout.layout4,R.layout.layout5}
```

//Current index of layout to be set.

```
int layoutIndex=0;
```

Now Inside OnCreate meathod, write below code

```
setContentView(layoutIds[layoutIndex]);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want! I feel kinda dumb that I didn't think of that before !